# Buttons on jumped frame not working anymore in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

Here's like what it's supposed to do:

1. There's a start button and a resume button at the home screen.
2. As the frames progress, there's a "save progress & return to home" button which will save the current frame and return to the home screen.
3. Back at the home screen, when you click "resume", it brings you back
   to the previous frame you were in.
4. And... so on and so forth.

I've done 1-3. But when it returns to the previous frame you were in, the buttons don't seem to work anymore. Like, you can't progress and move the frames forward anymore.

Here's a screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNDd2.png)

Then, here are the codes for both the actionscripts above:

Frame 1:

```
stop();

start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoIntro);

function gotoIntro(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop('intro');
}

resume_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoLastFrame);

function gotoLastFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(lastFrame);
    trace(currentFrame);
}
```

Frame 2:

```
var lastFrame:int = currentFrame;

next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNext);

function gotoNext(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
    lastFrame++;
    trace("current frame: " + currentFrame + "; saved frame: " + lastFrame);

}

back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHome);

function gotoHome(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop('home');
    trace(lastFrame);
}
```

This is for a future simple visual novel I'd like to make in the future. But lol I'm already stuck here hahaha. Can someone help how to move the frames forward again? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem are your frames. Frames are always hard to manage. When you go to the frame 2 an event listener is added to your Next button. When you then go to frame 3 and then leave to the frame 1 your button is removed from the stage. When you then go back to the frame 3 a NEW "next" button is added to the stage but there is no event listener for it (because you have skipped frame 2 where it is added).

An easy solution would be to move your novel frames to an own movieclip along with the code and call it "myNovel" as instance name. Move your start screen to another movieclip and call it "myStartScreen". Both of them are on the stage from frame 1 but your novel is invisible. Actually you need only one frame on your main timeline

Then when you click on start or next you make the start screen invisible and your novel visible. You dont even need to remember the frame because it will stay in the frame you have left.

Main timeline code:

```
// make novel invisible at the beginning
myNovel.visible = false;

function gotoHome():void
{
    // the novel will stay in the current frame
    myStartScreen.visible = true;
    myNovel.visible = false;
}

// startFromTheBeginning is an optional parameter
function gotoNovel(startFromTheBeginning:Boolean = false):void
{
    // the novel will stay in the current frame
    myStartScreen.visible = false;
    myNovel.visible = true;

    if(startFromTheBeginning)
    {
        myNovel.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Start screen code:

```
start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoIntro);

function gotoIntro(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // parent is the parent moveiclip (your main timeline with the code above)
    parent.gotoNovel(true); // start from the beginning
}

resume_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoLastFrame);

function gotoLastFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    parent.gotoNovel(); // this will make the novel visible that are in the frame that the user left
}
```

Novel code

```
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNext);

function gotoNext(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}

back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHome);

function gotoHome(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    parent.gotoHome();
}
```

Comment: Woah I think that would be a good idea, putting both the start and the novel in two different movie clips. I didn't even think of that :D Thanks!But, in this case, how do I get that function where I can go back to the start screen, and when I hit the "resume button" at the start screen, I can return back to that last frame I was in?

Comment: Reread my comments - the "Start screen code" should be in the strtscreen movieclip and "Novel code" - in the novel movieclip. That code is calling the functions on your main timeline